# How can I make 3D games in 4K that are a few megabytes?

Tags: 3d, architecture, flash, swf

I would like to make 3D games in 4K that are a few Megabytes (MB) in download size.

Is there a way to use 3D [Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) in games to reduce the file size ?
Or is there any other way to achieve the same level of compression achieved by Flash([.swf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF)) and [Swift3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_3D) ?

Comment: 4K woould be the resolution. No Textures, but lots of duplicates, such as grass.

Comment: There is stuff like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAyd5wSPQrM but it converts the svg to a mesh. Not sure if you want to animate things as well.

Comment: yes, 3D environment and animations.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. When your game uses 3d graphics, then changing the rendering resolution does not affect the filesize of the game. at all. You can render the same 3d scene in 640x480 px or 3840 × 2160px. You just need to change two numbers for that. Rendering in a higher resolution might look blurry if you show close-ups of low-resolution textures and have a bad framerate on low-end hardware, but what you get is technically a "4K game". Maybe your definition of "4k game" is more than just the screen resolution? Please specify.

Comment: @Philipp I think he also means to retain the quality of look just like how flash works at higher resolution. But doubt 3D vectors is a thing.

Comment: @Sidar vector graphics are the only kind of graphics supported on modern machines at all for 3D

Comment: In case you weren't aware that it was a thing, the 64kb demo scene included some amazing 3d graphics, like [fr-08 (aka ".the .product")](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3n3c_8Nn2Y).  It just took time and dedication. (Here's the [site](http://www.theproduct.de/) for the people who put that one together)

Comment: @Sidar No, they are a thing, irrespectively of how you look at things. Even if you would reject that polygons arent vector (they are) modern cad apps do use BREP which is as close analogy how 2D beziers work as you can get in 3D.

Comment: 3D graphics are inherently vectorized. Have you ever tried creating some?

Comment: Yes people i know that 3d is all vector math. (See my comment at the answer). At the time of writing the answer i was thinking in terms of tooling and creating detailed surfaces with layered polygons which is much harder to do instead of textures. But maybe grease pencil in blender can elevate that.

Comment: @Cort's link is outdated by the way, try http://www.farbrausch.de/ (fr-08 is [here](http://www.farbrausch.de/prod.py?which=17)) and most notably for this question you might be interested in [werkkzeug4](http://www.farbrausch.de/prod.py?which=168) and https://github.com/farbrausch/fr_public

Comment: @immibis
Yes, 3D graphics are inherently Vectorized during modeling, but they render in Rasterized format, NOT in Vector format. 

I am talking about 3D graphics that render in Vector format, so that it can scale without any Pixelation.

Comment: For a raster game or animation, SD content on HD display will cause pixelation, HD content on 4K display will cause pixelation, 4K content on 8K display will cause pixelation, etc.

For a Vector game or animation, pixelation is not a problem, as the content is rendered on-device. This does use more processing power and memory, but also takes a lot less bandwidth and storage. 

So, 4K Vector games could be 20-60 MB, instead of the 20-60 GB that the raster games take up now days.

Comment: @Neel Except for textures, 3D graphics are normally vectorized right until they appear on your screen. Have you tried scaling 3D graphics? Are you talking about the textures?

Comment: @immibis Have you ever tried playing a lower resolution 3D animation on a higher resolution monitor ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixelation

Comment: @Neel I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @immibis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:VectorBitmapExample.svg

Comment: @Neel yes and that's for a 2D drawing not a 3D model. Textures are 2D drawings displayed on the sides of 3D models. Are you talking about textures?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are ways to make nice 3d graphics with low memory footprint, however that requires you to have the right experience and knowledge. There are games like [.kkrieger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.kkrieger) which is a 3d first person shooter, with the size of a few kilobytes.

This is not just compression algorithms. You can't just make a massive game and press a button and suddenly its 100kb, that's not how it works.

Also you have to make the right balance between quality and file size. Sure we all want an HD experience with realistic graphics and very low memory requirements, but the higher quality, the heavier it gets.

Here are a few tricks:

- **Procedural generation**: The more data you generate on the fly, the less data need to be saved on the disk. Instead of having a massive static world, it's lighter (filesize-wise) to have a randomly generated one.
- **Repeating assets**: Have objects share the same textures, maybe switch some material settings to make them look different. For example, imagine you have one texture for the ground, one for the walls, and one for the ceiling. You can theoretically make an dungeon roguelike game, that has infinite size, because it keeps adding new rooms that are fully textured.
- **Custom Engine**: Game engines try to be as abstract as possible, to allow users to create a big variety of games. Unfortunately this comes with an overhead, that can't be avoided. Using a custom engine would ensure that there's not that many unnecessary data, and that everything is optimised to your needs. (Thanks @Sidar)

Comment: Kkrieger was also a custom engine. If you use any engine these days at minimum you have 10 megabytes just for engine capacity alone.

Comment: @Sidar That is an excellent point, I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Also I just realized OP is asking for literal "3d vector" graphics. i mean you could model your meshes  and use vertex colors with a flat shader, which does exactly that. It's cheaper too.

Comment: @Sidar I just noticed that as well. 3D graphics are anyway similar to Vector Graphics, as in, they scale without losing quality. I guess OP wants textures as 2D vector graphics?

Comment: @Sidar There are [small engine runtimes](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/20/unity-unveils-2018-roadmap-at-gdc/#small).

Comment: Note that kkrieger takes it to the extreme but their goal was 64k. If they can fit that in 64k you can fit a lot more in 4M. Or you can fit somewhat more and it'll be much easier to make fit.

Comment: @Sidar The terrain in The Witness is an example of this visual effect (though The Witness is not small).

Comment: Do not forget about compression as well.